# PHP explode string only if line does not end with '!'

Tags: php, parsing, explode

I'm writing a parser for a scripting programming language in PHP. The syntax of that scripting language looks like this:

```
ZOMFG
&This is a comment
(show "Hello, World\!");
```

This is a page written in that language, that displays Hello, World! in the browser. But I could also have code like this:

```
ZOMFG
&This is a comment !
on multiple !
lines.
(show !
"Hello, !
World\!!
");
```

For now I use `explode("\n", $content)` to explode the page's content to an array which has each line of code in a separate index.
So

```
ZOMFG
&This is a comment
(show "Hello, World\!");
```

becomes:

```
array('ZOMFG', '&This is a comment', '(show "Hello, World\!");');
```

When a line ends with a ! (except when the ! is escaped as \!), it should add that line, including the following line to the array as one single element. So

```
&This is a comment !
on multiple !
lines.
```

becomes

```
&This is a comment on multiple lines.
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use preg_split with a negative lookbehind.

(i'm finding an example)

```
$lines = preg_split('|(?<!\!)\n|', $code);
```

As per comments, aware that this causes both the newline characters and the ! to remain. Can't see an easier solution to this than str_replace at the moment - but imagine there is one ... !

Comment: nice idea, but that would not have the effect of stripping the !\n combination from the joined lines though.

Comment: Thanks man that worked. One problem: the ! remains in the middle of the line. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: str_replace('\!', "!", $line);